# Always get "Microsoft Addin Installer" popup message when starting Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Each time when I start Excel 2010, I will always see a Microsoft Addin installer" dialog, I need to press "Not install" button to dismiss it. It is really annoying. Is there a way to dismiss this dialog for ever?

Comment: What version of Office?  Office 365 is very complete. If this is your personal copy of Office, do an Office Repair from Control Panel, Programs and Features and complete the installation. If a Company license, ask "work" to assist you.

Comment: @John I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: @alancc,, check File,Option,, Add IN,, GO,,, find the recent Add IN popping,, disable it.

Comment: Old versions of Office could install "some" and then make your install "more" later. In this case, uninstall Office, restart, install Office again and install it fully.

Comment: @RajeshS, Your solution works perfectly. The only thing I need to mention is that I need to run as the administrator to do the task.

Comment: @alancc,,, in that case whenever you want to RUN any app/AddIN then select it, Right click,, from Pop up menu find command RUN as Administrator. If All my suggestion works for you then confirm through comments, I'll then post it as ANSWER !!

Comment: @RajeshS, Yes, Your solution works so please post it as an answer. Thaks.

Comment: @alancc,,, now I've posted the solution ☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To get rid from the issue do the followings:*

- Hit **F**ile command then **O**ption.
- Find & click **A**dd-Ins.
- From the dialogue box, at bottom you find **G**O button, click it.
- Now from **A**dd-Ins available list box, find the Add IN creating problem, and disable it.

---

*For another issue:*

- Whenever you want to RUN any application/Add-Ins then select it, **R**ight click, and from Pop up menu find and hit the command **R**UN as Administrator.

*Specially in case of Add-Ins, better use built in feature:*

- You need to copy the Add-Ins in the following path to select/enable.

  ```
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\Library

   C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns
  ```

**Note:** *Path may vary, so work accordingly.*

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help you @alancc  ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple different versions of excel installed? If so, try uninstalling the other version completely.

If not, refer to the steps below：

1.Navigate to the path below

C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\Office Setup Controller

2.Find a program named "SETUP".

[image]

3.Change the program named "SETUP" to any name.

Comment: I have both Excel 2003 and 2010 installed. Is it possible to not uninstall Excel 2003?

Comment: In general, we don't recommend installing multiple versions of office on the same device, which can always be confusing.

Comment: @Binggo_MSFT you seem to be saying people should not have different versions of Office on the same computer? Can you provide a reference, as this does not seem to be the Microsoft line. Sure there are a few things to watch out for, but I don't think it's that uncommon for people to use side-by-side versions for one reason or another. Indeed Microsoft publish guidance on how to [Install and use different versions of Office on the same PC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/install-and-use-different-versions-of-office-on-the-same-pc-6ebb44ce-18a3-43f9-a187-b78c513788bf).